# How to make several elements elegantly non-focusable?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a window overlaying my actual content. When visible, this window (and it's children) should be the only elements receiving focus via Mouse and the Tab-key. Any background elements should not be focusable anymore.

I am certain that I can prevent the elements in the background from receiving focus or being clicked using `pointer-events: none;` . I know that any focus via the Tab-key can be prevented by setting a `tabindex="-1"` on that specific element. So I am wondering whether there is a more elegant solution to that, rather than applying a negative `tabindex` to each element individually.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Put a wrapper around all your content except the window. When the window is displayed you can apply the `pointer-events: none;` style and the `inert` HTML property to the wrapper to affect all its children. Note that `inert` is very unfortunately not supported on Firefox.